# JpaRepository doesn't save the last elemen in a list of attachments

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Springboot application that exposes a `@PostMapping` endpoint to save an entity, through `JpaRepository`.

This entity has a list of attachments.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    // fields
    private Set<EFile> attachments = new HashSet<>();
    // getters and setters
}
```

.. where `EFile` is a custom entity, so built:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class EFile {
    // fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

This Entity is used all over the project, and it doesn't seem to give this problem for other entities.

I do receive an Array of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` from the `request`:

```
MultipartFile[] attachments;
```

.. which I cycle through to save them one at a time.

Attachments are saved in a different table, so, first, I save the `Entity` from the request. Then, I save the `attachments` in the table and bind the Attachment `id` to the Entity `id` into a Pivot table.

Here is the `forEach`:

```
if (!Utils.isEmpty(attachments)) {
    for (MultipartFile attachment : attachments) {
        attachmentManager.addAttachment(entity, attachment, directory);
    }
}
```

.. inside the `addAttachment` method there is the `JpaRepository` that does the automatic `save()`

The problem is: somehow it doesn't save the last item of the array, even though it actually executes the save without any error through the whole Array, but it is not persisted into the Database.

The workaround is pretty simple.. I just re-added the first element of the `Multipart[]` to the `attachments` so that no files get missing, but I would like to know how is this possible. I am not using any `Transaction`. Wondering if somebody had the same problem..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the root cause is usage of `Set` and `@Data`, however I would prefer to see the code.

Comment: I know the code I shared is not so reproducible, but the project structure is very complex. Plus, even if `Set` and `@Data` are the problem, I don't think I can changfe them since the `EFile` is widely used in the project. But you gave me and idea! Thank you